# Elastic Search returning less number of documents as response

Tags: elasticsearch

I have put 4 documents in one index of elastic search.
QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery() returns me all 4 documents.

When I run the query_string query , I get lesser number of results which is 2 ,even when all match my criteria

I have tried using queryStringQuery and boolQuery with should() params as my text search . Both of the above returns me 2 result.

```
String query = "(username:email@email.com) AND (docSetName:BHOBHO OR BHOBHO12)";
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(query);
SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.prepareSearch()
    .setIndices("curion_hvuhdw").setQuery(qb);
SearchResponse response = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();        
System.out.println("response"+response);
```

I expect all the 4 documents to be show up , but its showing only one from each document set. All are under one index.

Any advice/suggestions where I am going wrong , would be really helpful

Comment: Please add the expected documents.

Comment: @NishantSaini,  I cannot place it here because it contains confidential information throughout.

Comment: Prepare sample docs with similar kind of data (not the confidential one) with only the fields which are being used in query. We can't help without knowing the expected output documents.

Comment: Ok @NishantSaini , will try to prepare and put it here.